# Get Display method to return boolean? - JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a class called GUI which manages my application. When the user wants to delete his account in my program, I want a warning box to pop up and demand him to confirm or cancel his action, so he doesn't accidentally delete his account.

```
 package application;

 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.control.Label;
 import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
 import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
 import javafx.stage.*;

 /**
  * An Alert Box for the GUI
  * to display errors to the user.
  *
  */
public class AlertBox
{   
Stage window;

public boolean display(String title, String message)
{       
    boolean cancel = false;

    window = new Stage();                                                               // Create the stage.        

    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);                                    // If window is up, make user handle it.
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setMinHeight(350);
    window.setMinWidth(250);

    VBox root = new VBox();                 // Root layout.

    Label warning = new Label(message);     // Message explaining what is wrong.

    HBox buttonLayout = new HBox();         // The yes and cancel button.

    Button yesButton = new Button("Yes");   // Yes button for the user.
    Button noButton = new Button("No");     // No button for the user.

    yesButton.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        cancel = false;
    });

    noButton.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        cancel = true;
    });
    buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(yesButton, noButton);


    root.getChildren().addAll(warning, buttonLayout);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

/**
 * Closes the window and returns whether the user said yes or no.
 * @param variable
 * @return
 */
private boolean close(boolean variable)
{
    window.close();
    return variable;
}
```

}

I want my GUI class to know exactly what occurred while the user was in the AlertBox class. Did the user click Yes or No? So I thought about making the display method boolean. Here's where the problem is, my event listener expression cannot return any values because it is inside of a callback of type void. Then I thought, "Oh I'll just make the close method return a boolean". But then I remembered that the original function I called was:

```
AlertBox warning = new AlertBox;
boolean userWantsToDelete = warning.display("Warning!", "You are about to delete your account. Are you sure you would like to do this?");
```

which wants the display method to return a variable, NOT the close method. I can't just call close either, as that won't work. What can I do to assist in this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is close to a duplicate of: [Block program execution until user clicks button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121580/block-program-execution-until-user-clicks-button)

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but how about passing `EventHandler` interface to display method?

Comment: * actually it would be better to set it in your class before calling `display` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can use JavaFX Alerts to perform your task easily :**

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Warning !");
    alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to perform this action ?");

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
     // delete user
 }
```

**result.get()** returns a boolean value. So you can check whether user clicked  `ButtonType.OK` or `ButtonType.CANCEL` by comparing it inside the if condition.

Here is an example for you to understand :
[image]

With default Alert you get two buttons one is OK button and the other one is Cancel. But if you wish to customize the Alert you can add your own button types into it like below :

```
ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("Two");
ButtonType buttonTypeThree = new ButtonType("Three");
```

And add them to the alert :

```
alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo, buttonTypeThree);
```

So you can check which button was pressed by the user

```
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
    // ... user chose "One"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeTwo) {
    // ... user chose "Two"
} else{
    // ... user chose "Three"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand this whatsoever. Are these JavaFX commands? .setContentText, .setHeaderText, .showAndWait(), etc? What does Optional<ButtonType> mean?

Comment: @Hatefiend yes, he is using JavaFX Dialog class.

Comment: How would you do it without using the Dialog class? There must be a way to do this by using my own classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Mutable Object (`MutableBool` class) as a passed parameter. Since the Mutable Object is passed as a pointer, you can assign a value to check out of the method.

Add class:

```
class MutableBool{
    private boolean value;

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and some change for your code:

```
public boolean display(String title, String message, MutableBool answer){
    ...
    answer.setValue(true);
}
```

Comment: Okay so I would do like: `boolean variable = false` (assume the user is going to say no). `AlertBox warning = new AlertBox();` `warning.display("Warning", "Be careful!", variable);` Then, in display method, if I change the value of `variable`, it will also display in my GUI class? I didn't know primitive types are pass by reference.

Comment: This won't work. Boolean classes are immutable in java. You can access the instance answer from the outside, but you can't do changes to it. 

If you assign a new value to the variable answer inside your class/method,  a new object will be used there, which you  can't access from the outside. (as you're holding a reference to the old instance from the outside)

you could do something like that with a mutable object.

Comment: @DThought, Sorry, I didn't take it into account. I changed answer.

Comment: I was just thinking this. It's so weird how something like this works but just passing in a boolean does not. Is this considered bad programming?

Comment: you can do this, but how do you know user pressed the button already?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without `EventHandler`. You can do something like this if you really want to use your own class:

```
AlertBox alert = new AlertBox("title","message");
alert.setYesAction( e -> {
    //TO-DO
});
alert.setNoAction( e -> {
    //TO-DO
});
alert.showAndWait();
```

And if you want to check `cancel` status no matter if user pressed button or not you can call: `alert.isCanceled()`;

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 * An Alert Box for the GUI to display errors to the user.
 *
 */
public class AlertBox extends Stage {
    private boolean cancel = false;
    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> yesAction = null;
    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> noAction = null;

    public AlertBox(String title, String message) {
        super();
        initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); // If window is up,
        // make user handle
        // it.
        setTitle(title);
        setMinHeight(350);
        setMinWidth(250);

        VBox root = new VBox(); // Root layout.

        Label warning = new Label(message); // Message explaining what is wrong.

        HBox buttonLayout = new HBox(); // The yes and cancel button.

        Button yesButton = new Button("Yes"); // Yes button for the user.
        Button noButton = new Button("No"); // No button for the user.

        yesButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            cancel = false;
            yesAction.handle(new ActionEvent());
        });

        noButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            cancel = true;
            noAction.handle(new ActionEvent());
        });
        buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(yesButton, noButton);

        root.getChildren().addAll(warning, buttonLayout);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        setScene(scene);
    }

    public void setYesAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> yesAction){
        this.yesAction = yesAction;
    }
    public void setNoAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> noAction){
        this.noAction = noAction;
    }

    public boolean isCanceled(){
        return cancel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can handle in main Class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        final AlertBox warning = new AlertBox("Warning!",
                "You are about to delete your account. Are you sure you  would like to do this?");    

            warning.addCancelListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    System.out.println("Tschüss");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for confidence");
                }
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}

package application;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * An Alert Box for the GUI
 * to display errors to the user.
 */
public class AlertBox {
    Stage window;
    ObjectProperty<Boolean> cancel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

    public AlertBox(final String title, final String message) {
        cancel.setValue(null);
        display(title, message);
    }

    private void display(final String title, final String message) {
        window = new Stage(); // Create the stage.

        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); // If window is up, make user handle it.
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setMinHeight(350);
        window.setMinWidth(250);
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        final VBox root = new VBox(); // Root layout.

        final Label warning = new Label(message); // Message explaining  what is wrong.

        final HBox buttonLayout = new HBox(); // The yes and cancel button.

        final Button yesButton = new Button("Yes"); // Yes button for the user.
        final Button noButton = new Button("No"); // No button for the user.

        yesButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            cancel.set(false);
            close();
        });

        noButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            cancel.set(true);
            close();
        });

        buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(yesButton, noButton);

        root.getChildren().addAll(warning, buttonLayout);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the window
     *
     * @param variable
     */
    private void close() {
        window.close();
    }

    public void addCancelListener(final ChangeListener<Boolean> listener) {
        cancel.addListener(listener);
    }
}
```